# Volatile inter file or inter - thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, volatile, extern

I was wondering whether volatile keyword takes care of inter-thread affairs or inter file - via extern affairs or both?

I did experiments but the results were bit confusing..

Comment: You need to be more specific. What experiments? What was confusing? What is `inter-file`?

Comment: There is an interesting article about `volatile` and concurrency [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/volatile-vs-volatile/212701484).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++ the `volatile` keyword has **nothing** to do with synchronization **at all**! It is neither taking care of anything inter thread nor inter process. The only purpose of `volatile` is making sure that the compiler creates code that does access the `volatile` variable time every time the code says it does. One propose for the `volatile` keyword is memory mapped I/O.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify a variable from multiple threads, `volatile` isn't correct... look into [Interlocked functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684122(v=vs.85).aspx)